# Python(2.7):Bug class program error of indentation

Tags: python-2.7

Whenever I compile my code

```
import pygame,sys
from classes import *
pygame.init()
SCREENWIDTH,SCREENHEIGHT = 640, 360
screen = pygame.display.set_mode ((SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 24
bug = Bug(0,100,40,40,"bug.png")
while True:
    # PROCESSING
    for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
     #LOGIC
     bug.motion()
     #LOGIC
     #DRAW
     screen.fill((0,0,0))
     BaseClass.allsprites.draw(screen)
     pygame.display.flip()
     #DRAW
     clock.tick(FPS)
```

It shows the following error:

File "practice.py", line 16
    bug.motion()
               ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Answer (score 0):

Every line after `sys.exit()` has five spaces, when they should have four.

```
import pygame,sys
from classes import *
pygame.init()
SCREENWIDTH,SCREENHEIGHT = 640, 360
screen = pygame.display.set_mode ((SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 24
bug = Bug(0,100,40,40,"bug.png")
while True:
    # PROCESSING
    for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    #LOGIC
    bug.motion()
    #LOGIC
    #DRAW
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    BaseClass.allsprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    #DRAW
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Now its showing this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "practice.py", line 16, in <module>
    bug.motion()
AttributeError: 'Bug' object has no attribute 'motion'

Comment: That error is probably appearing because the `bug` object has no method called `motion`. It's hard to say how to fix that, since I don't know how you defined the `Bug` class.

Comment: class Bug(BaseClass):

     List = pygame.sprite.Group()
     def__init__(self, x, y, width, height, image_string):
          BaseClass.__init__(self, x, y, width, height, image_string)
          Bug.List.add(self)
          self.velx = 0

def motion(self): 
     self.rect.x += self.velx